# React Form - I want to know how to modify the form validation with yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, yup

At the moment, my form is connected to my mongoDB Database - and a user can log in with a registered account.

The validation error messages are only displayed when no data has been entered in the input fields - how would I alter the schema validation in a way that only displays the error message "password is not correct" - when it is not matching the user's existing credentials.

As you can see, the user can only log in if the credentials do exist - I'm just not certain how to alter the validation messages. I've gone through the yup documentation, and haven't had much luck.

If there is a better alternative for form validation, or a solution to this issue, please let me know.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../Components/Zustand - Auth/authLogin"

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

const schema = yup.object({
  username: yup.string().required("Username is a required field"),
  password: yup.string().required("The password that you've entered is incorrect"),
});

function Login(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn } = useAuth();

  const onUsernameChange = (event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  };

  const onPasswordChange = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const formSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/login", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: data.username, password: data.password }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          props.router.navigate("/");
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
          console.log("login failed");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
    console.log(data);
  };


  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h1>Log in</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
        <Input
          id="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={onUsernameChange} 
          label="Username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          register={{ ...register("username") }}
          errorMessage={errors.username?.message}
        />

        <Input
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={onPasswordChange} 
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          register={{ ...register("password") }}
          errorMessage={errors.password?.message}
        />

        <button>Log in</button>
      </form>
      <button className="button-link" onClick={() => props.onFormSwitch("signup")}>
        Don't have an account? Register here.
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Yup handles submission errors, though I may be wrong. However you can handle these fairly simply using plain React. You'll just need to store the error information in state somehow.

A simple way to do this is to store the message returned by the server in the case of an error (you could also customize this by translating a server error to more user-friendly language if you want/need).

Here's an example:

```
function Login() {
    const [submissionError, setSubmissionError] = React.useState("");

    const formSubmit = (data) => {
        fetch(
            // ...
        ).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                // ...
            } else {
                // either:
                response.json().then((responseData) => {
                    setSubmissionError(responseData.error); // example JSON structure
                })
                // or:
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    setSubmissionError("Invalid username or password.");
                } else if (response.status === 500) {
                    setSubmissionError("Something went wrong, please try again in a few moments.")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {submissionError && <p>{submissionError}</p>}
            {/* ... */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Note that if you go with option 2 (using the response HTTP status to set the error) you can clean up the code by removing the `else` block and just using `else if` for those conditions.

Comment: Appreciate the help, Henry. I will give this a go as soon as I have the time, and let you know how it goes.